# Why is this modelica model overconstrained?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am learning to use modelica (through the connection editor) and am attempting modelling of a combustion engine. I have written a model for a crank-rod system. However, when attempting to attach the crank-rod systems to the crankshaft, the model becomes overconstrained. This is confusing to me since I would expect it physically to be underconstrained at this point, since the rod ends are still not attached to anything. Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong would be much obliged.

crank-rod model (removed annotations for clarity)

```
connector crank_rod
import Modelica.Units.SI.*;

parameter Length stroke;
parameter Angle toppingOutAngle(displayUnit = "deg");
Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Interfaces.Flange_a crank;
Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.Flange_a rod_end;

equation
crank.tau = rod_end.f * 0.5 * stroke * sin(toppingOutAngle - crank.phi);
rod_end.s = 0.5 * stroke * (1 - cos(toppingOutAngle - crank.phi));
end crank_rod;
```

Connecting four crank-rods (four cylinder engine) to the rotational flange that represents the crankshaft

```
model fourCylinderBank
v8.crank_rod crank1;
v8.crank_rod crank2;
v8.crank_rod crank3;
v8.crank_rod crank4;
Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Interfaces.Flange_a crank;

equation
connect(crank1.crank, crank) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-66, -36}, {-66, -72}, {-2, -72}}));
connect(crank2.crank, crank) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-32, -36}, {-30, -36}, {-30, -72}, {-2, -72}}));
connect(crank3.crank, crank) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -36}, {-2, -36}, {-2, -72}}));
connect(crank4.crank, crank) annotation(
    Line(points = {{50, -36}, {50, -72}, {-2, -72}}));
end fourCylinderBank;
```

This results in 22 equations for 18 variables.

I expected the above model to be underconstrained, after which it would become correctly constrained by attaching piston systems to the crank rod ends.

Comment: Did you make `crank_rod`  a connector on purpose? It should be a model. Connectors must not contain equations.

Answer (score 3):

I found some issues:

1. The `crank_rod` is not a connector, but a model - since it contains equations. I have added default values for the parameters - not sure if they make sense - but it allows a simulation of the model.

   ```
   model crank_rod
     import Modelica.Units.SI.*;

     parameter Length stroke=0.1;
     parameter Angle toppingOutAngle(displayUnit = deg")=80*Modelica.Constants.pi/180;
     Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Interfaces.Flange_a crank;
     Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.Flange_a rod_end;

   equation 
     crank.tau = rod_end.f * 0.5 * stroke * sin(toppingOutAngle - crank.phi);
     rod_end.s = 0.5 * stroke * (1 - cos(toppingOutAngle - crank.phi));
   end crank_rod;
   ```
2. The overall system is reported to be singular. You can solve this issue by adding an inertia to the overall model (removed annotation for readability):

   ```
   model fourCylinderBank
     v8.crank_rod crank1;
     v8.crank_rod crank2;
     v8.crank_rod crank3;
     v8.crank_rod crank4;
     Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Interfaces.Flange_a crank;
     Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.Inertia inertia(J=0.1);

   equation 
     connect(crank1.crank, crank);
     connect(crank2.crank, crank);
     connect(crank3.crank, crank);
     connect(crank4.crank, crank);
     connect(crank, inertia.flange_a);
   end fourCylinderBank;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare `crank_rod` as a **model**, not as a connector.
It then checks ok in Dymola at least.

Connector is for the things you connect like flanges and pins (and may not contain equations):
https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.6/class-predefined-types-and-declarations.html#specialized-classes